# How to compare two values of different types and determine the largest from a grabbed table data

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

I grabbed few lines of data from a url. I am trying to compare one largest value of a type against another. Im missing something as I failed to extract it properly.

```
import requests, re, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
trim = re.compile(r'[^\d,.]+')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
url = "https://poocoin.app/rugcheck/0x8076c74c5e3f5852037f31ff0093eeb8c8add8d3/top-holders"
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(8)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
t = soup.find('table', class_='table table-bordered table-condensed text-small')

bigwallet = 0
bigcontract = 0
contractbalance = 0
walletbalance = 0

for row in soup.select("tr:has(td)")[:10]:
    addr = row.find_all("td")[0].text[0:]
    trans = row.find_all("td")[4].text[0:]
    bal = row.find_all("td")[5].text[0:].strip()
    tbal = trim.sub('', bal).replace(",", "")
    tbal = float(tbal)
    wtype = row.find_all("td")[2].text[0:].strip()

    if (str(wtype) == "Contract"):
        contractbalance = float(tbal)
    else:
        walletbalance = float(tbal)
    if (walletbalance) > (contractbalance):
        bigwallet = walletbalance
    else:
        bigcontract = contractbalance

    bigwallet = bigwallet
    bigcontract = bigcontract
    print(" {}    {:<20} {:<5} {:>5} ".format(addr, bal, trans, wtype))
print (" Largest Contract: {}           Largest Wallet: {} ".format(bigwallet, bigcontract))
driver.quit()
```

Current Output: #-- current problematic output

```
0x9adc6fb78cefa07e13e9294f150c1e8c1dd566c0    12,704,309,869,844.8669   325911  Contract 
0xc95063d946242f26074a76c8a2e94c9d735dfc78    7,745,539,348,064.8244    11      Wallet  
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001    423,229,310,780,801.1327  159     Contract 
0xff3dd404afba451328de089424c74685bf0a43c9    15,407,439,439,186.9579   389180  Contract 
0x86b695aaa2600668cec754c7827357626b188054    10,311,345,756,789.1980   9       Wallet 
0x010b86c90654905611b31dbfaf5883ba616b9833    0.0000                    1       Wallet 
   #-- problematic part of my code
Largest Contract: 0           Largest Wallet: 15407439439186.957
```

Wanted Output:

```
Largest Contract: 423,229,310,780,801.1327     Largest Wallet: 10,311,345,756,789.1980 

0x9adc6fb78cefa07e13e9294f150c1e8c1dd566c0     12,704,309,869,844.8669   325911  Contract 
0xc95063d946242f26074a76c8a2e94c9d735dfc78      7,745,539,348,064.8244       11  Wallet  
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001    423,229,310,780,801.1327      159  Contract 
0xff3dd404afba451328de089424c74685bf0a43c9     15,407,439,439,186.9579   389180  Contract 
0x86b695aaa2600668cec754c7827357626b188054     10,311,345,756,789.1980        9  Wallet 
0x010b86c90654905611b31dbfaf5883ba616b9833                      0.0000        1  Wallet
```

Comment: Not able to understand the process you are doing to compare those values. `(walletbalance) > (contractbalance)` always returns `False` and in last line in `print` statement, for Largest contract, you are passing bigwallet value.

Comment: Im also had been running around with this. I felt so drain. What I am trying to accomplish is basically determine the largest Contract Value and the largest Wallet Value based on the table data I grabbed.

Comment: As I said dont know how you are comparing, and if those values depend on each other. If you are comparing respective type of values, then go for listing those values and taking maximum of them. Already tried have posted the same. Try it once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can collect all those values to respective list and then take the `max` value among those.

```
bigwallet = [] # List of wallet values
bigcontract = [] # List of contract values

for row in soup.select("tr:has(td)")[:10]:
    addr = row.find_all("td")[0].text[0:]
    trans = row.find_all("td")[4].text[0:]
    bal = row.find_all("td")[5].text[0:].strip()
    tbal1 = trim.sub('', bal).replace(",", "")
    tbal = float(tbal1)
    wtype = row.find_all("td")[2].text[0:].strip()

    if (str(wtype) == "Contract"):
        bigcontract.append(tbal) # Append to bigcontract if its a contact one else append to bigwallet.
    else:
        bigwallet.append(tbal)
    #print(" {}    {:<20} {:<5} {:>5} ".format(addr, bal, trans, wtype))
print (" Largest Contract: {}           Largest Wallet: {} ".format(max(bigcontract),max(bigwallet))) # print max of bigcontact and big wallet
driver.quit()
```

```
 Largest Contract: 423234543343603.1           Largest Wallet: 10311473240313.781
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of all those comparisons, you can directly use the built-in `max()` function to get the maximum values of Contract and Wallet.

Here is the code:

```
import requests, re, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
trim = re.compile(r'[^\d,.]+')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
url = "https://poocoin.app/rugcheck/0x8076c74c5e3f5852037f31ff0093eeb8c8add8d3/top-holders"
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(8)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
t = soup.find('table', class_='table table-bordered table-condensed text-small')

bigwallet = 0
bigcontract = 0
contractbalance = 0
walletbalance = 0

for row in soup.select("tr:has(td)")[:10]:
    addr = row.find_all("td")[0].text[0:]
    trans = row.find_all("td")[4].text[0:]
    bal = row.find_all("td")[5].text[0:].strip()
    tbal = trim.sub('', bal).replace(",", "")
    tbal = float(tbal)
    wtype = row.find_all("td")[2].text[0:].strip()

    if (str(wtype) == "Contract"):
        contractbalance = float(tbal)
        bigcontract = max(bigcontract, contractbalance)
    else:
        walletbalance = float(tbal)
        bigwallet = max(bigwallet, walletbalance)
    
    print(" {}    {:<20} {:<5} {:>5} ".format(addr, bal, trans, wtype))
print (" Largest Contract: {}           Largest Wallet: {} ".format(bigcontract, bigwallet))
driver.quit()
```

```
 0x9adc6fb78cefa07e13e9294f150c1e8c1dd566c0    12,705,728,079,579.6744 325911 Contract 
 0xc95063d946242f26074a76c8a2e94c9d735dfc78    7,745,635,776,415.0881 11    Wallet 
 0xa8736b9585a01d6dcc1b6e2fc9dc208552c34b58    20,000,000,001,566.1322 6     Contract 
 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001    423,234,579,788,211.4459 159   Contract 
 0xff3dd404afba451328de089424c74685bf0a43c9    15,372,532,667,134.5367 389418 Contract 
 0x86b695aaa2600668cec754c7827357626b188054    10,311,474,128,231.8625 9     Wallet 
 0x010b86c90654905611b31dbfaf5883ba616b9833    0.0000               1     Wallet 
 0x0add13cde4c61734f46e245b1b5fe3afe9b6bc29    0.0000               1     Wallet 
 0xc5becfc3771400ac372c3b1a0712899c72f75792    39.1084              1     Wallet 
 0xcc64ea842fcde4283cf239259f7462ef809c44fd    149,028.9837         36    Wallet 
 Largest Contract: 423234579788211.44           Largest Wallet: 10311474128231.863
```